# JSON.Net, customizing serialization of List<T>

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm serializing a `List<T>`, which I suppose is an array of objects when you think about it.  When serializing the populated `List<T>`, I get a result similar to the following:

```
[
  {
    "foo": "a1",
    "bar": "b1"
  },
  {
    "foo": "a2",
    "bar": "b2"
  },
  {
    "foo": "a3",
    "bar": "b3"
  }
]
```

This is of course a json array of objects as you'd expect.  However, I have a different need. I require the serialization of the `List<T>` to be separate objects as shown.

```
{
    "foo": "a1",
    "bar": "b1"
}
{
    "foo": "a2",
    "bar": "b2"
}
{
    "foo": "a3",
    "bar": "b3"
}
```

I'm planning to use RegEx to update the json string, but before I went through that step, I wanted to find out if there is an in-the-box solution in json.net to deal with specific formatting needs.  Granted, I have not read every line of documentation but, I've read a good bit of it and nothing stood out.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you serialize each item of the list on its own?  You could then concatenate the results afterward if needed.

Comment: That isn't valid json, so I doubt you can get json.net to output it. Why do you need it in that format?

Comment: Also curious to know the answer to Jason P's question. If you really need what you posted, you could foreach your list and serialize each element individually into a List<string>.

Comment: The target for this is AWS Redshift.  When I loaded the original json.net serialized file Redshift COPY command interpreted the whole array as a single object and because of the size of the object, errored out.   The only way I could get the file into Redshift was to use the format in the second example.

Perhaps the real issue here is not json.net, but perhaps, its more to do with how I'm instructing Redshift to parse my file.

Thanks for your feedback.  Through your questions, it made me realize I was trying to solve a Redshift problem with my application and that's a terrible approach.

Answer (score 1):

My approach was wrong here.  The real issue is at the target for where the json will be ingested.  Rather than trick json.net into serializing invalid json, I am going to refocus my energy on why the target system is interpreting my json file incorrectly.

Answer (score -2):

Why dont try to use NEWTONSOFT it will make all the work for you just have to implement the library and return the Json ready to use

```
public static string ToJson(object obj)
{

    //Remember to JSON.parse() in aspx so you can work with data returned
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
}
```

Hope this help you

Comment: JSON.NET == Newtonsoft. He's already using it and he wants a custom serialization.

Comment: Sorry my fault , didn't get the tittle :(